# How can I show the user's email in a textview after it is logged in?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have this problem: I want to show the user's email in a `textview` but I dont know how to do it, I try this

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
ShowEmail = findViewById(R.id.ShowEmail);
ShowEmail.setText("Hola"+user.getEmail());
```

But it shows nothing, even I try this:

```
String hello = "Hi";

if(user != null) {
    hello = hello.concat(" ").concat(user.getMail());
}

ShowEmail.setText(hello);
```

This is the code of my xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="@string/Hola"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ShowEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
```

But the textview goes blank, I use firebase to register the user.

**UPDATE**

This appear in user.getEmail:

`This inspection analyzes method control and data flow to report possible conditions that are always true or false, expressions whose value is statically proven to be constant, and situations that can lead to nullability contract violations.
Variables, method parameters and return values marked as @Nullable or @NotNull are treated as nullable (or not-null, respectively) and used during the analysis to check nullability contracts, e.g. report NullPointerException (NPE) errors that might be produced.
More complex contracts can be defined using @Contract annotation, for example:
@Contract("_, null -> null") — method returns null if its second argument is null @Contract("_, null -> null; _, !null -> !null") — method returns null if its second argument is null and not-null otherwise @Contract("true -> fail") — a typical assertFalse method which throws an exception if true is passed to it 
The inspection can be configured to use custom @Nullable
@NotNull annotations (by default the ones from annotations.jar will be used)`

Comment: Check whether this is a problem in your TextView

Comment: How? I do not know what to do anymore

Comment: Pls post corresponding xml code about your TextView

Comment: I just added it

Comment: Change android:text="" to android:text="test content"  then remove other code that change this attribute and check whether this work correctly . what's more , you'd better post some more xml code to figure out why this happen .

Comment: If I put text if it shows, but does not show the email

Comment: I put all the xml code

Comment: Figure out whether email is null . If textview works correctly ,something wrong in your code about  ShowEmail.setText

Comment: Oh, In the Firebase say this: `{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}`

Comment: You need to cast your `View` in a `TextView`, like this: `TextView showEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ShowEmail);`

Comment: @Cyrus Look the update please

Answer (score 2):

try to do this,
Declare this outside the oncreate

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
```

And inside your oncreate

```
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    TextView ShowEmailt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ShowEmail);
    String hello = "Hi";

    if(user != null) {
        hello = hello.concat(" ").concat(user.getMail());
    }
    else{
        hello = "User not logged in";
    }
    showEmail.setText(hello);
```

Hope this'll help

Comment: Nothing, tye textview goes blank, and the user.getMail say this: "Argument 'user.getEmail()' might be null"

Comment: Hi, try doing this. You haven't casted your textview to Textview type
TextView ShowEmailt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ShowEmail);

Comment: show the same: Argument 'user.getEmail()' might be null"

Comment: Then there may be a problem with the signin, the user is not signed in, that's why you're getting "might be null" warning. Please recheck the signin codes, and the firebase connectivity . [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth) crosschek your code with this documentation

Comment: I have the registered user in the database